# Debounce MacBook pro Keybboard

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

Is it possible to debounce a MacBBook keyboard via a script? I have the [obbbnoxious double "b"](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7754550) problem wherein my keyboard inserts two "b" characters abbout half the time (also occasionally the r and i characters, but less often). The keyboard is bbuilt into the case, which makes the replacement a cool $1015 ($680 for parts, and $335 for labor). Hence, I'm hoping for a software solution.

Comment: This is a good question, and the indicated duplicate is not actually a duplicate nor is the answer below actually an answer. It would be nice to reopen it, to get interim options before taking advantage of [Apple's extended warranty offer](https://www.apple.com/support/keyboard-service-program-for-macbook-and-macbook-pro/).

Comment: Here's a question that actually is a near-duplicate of this one. The asker ended up writing and releasing their own debouncing code: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/246840/debounce-mechanical-keyboard-in-os-x

Comment: For what it's worth, a few months after asking this question, apple introduced a [keyboard replacement program for MacBooks](https://www.apple.com/support/keyboard-service-program-for-macbook-and-macbook-pro/), even for those without apple care.  This was a lifesaver for me, though obviously this won't help everyone else who needs as it's only for specific Macbooks...

Comment: The duplicate resolution is correct, but the question it was duplicated is wrong. It's about debouncing, not about fixing the hardware. The right question to refer would be, for example, https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/246840/debounce-mechanical-keyboard-in-os-x

Answer (score -1):

Without knowing if Apple Techs fully evaluated the state of your system (you seem to have asked someone the repair cost), in the past batteries will swell and cause odd keyboard behavior before proceeding to various other bad effects including:

> Warping the back cover
>   Leaking acid into the internals

Not saying I am right or wrong, but you have a chance to get ahead of this if it is true.

Comment: This does not answer the question: a software means to debounce a key. The author also clearly stated that they don't want an Apple service.